# MongoDb $where clause returning incorrect results

Tags: mongodb

I have the below document in EMPLOYEES collection.

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("57d1a113666f6fc012f2708f"),
"employee_id" : 107,
"first_name" : "Diana",
"last_name" : "Lorentz",
"email" : "DLORENTZ",
"phone_number" : "590.423.5567",
"hire_date" : "07-FEB-99",
"job_id" : "IT_PROG",
"salary" : 4200,
"manager_id" : 103,
"department_id" : 60}
```

i'm getting the correct results when i run this query `db.EMPLOYEES.find({$where: " return false "});`

if i execute the the same logic in other way using the below query, its returning records from EMPLOYEES collection which is incorrect.

```
`db.EMPLOYEES.find({$where: function(){return false}});`
```

What is wrong in 2nd query ?

Comment: what is your `$where` is actually doing ?

Comment: I'm a beginner. i know above query does nothing. i'm trying to understand how where clause works in MongoDB. its supposed to return 0 records but it is not. could you explain why it is producing inconsistent results ?

Comment: Is this a Bug in MongoDB ?

Comment: Well before declaring bug, I'd suggest look again at your query and see what documentation is saying.